# Android BitmapShader memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I've a memory leak in my android app, that cause outOfMemory exception. I've done a memory analysis thought MAT, and the result is that there're ' 480 instances of "android.graphics.BitmapShader", loaded by "" occupy 42,611,792 (81.71%) bytes.' I'm using a lot of Bitmaps and Drawable, but in my whole project I never use BitmapShader. I guess how could I reduce the number of objects or recycle them, if I never instantiate no one of them.
Thanks to everyone

Comment: maybe some components or views use bitmapShaders implicitly... Which kind of standard or third-party custom views you're using in your project? Such leaks often happen when you don't clear all references to memory consumpting objects.

Comment: Thank you for answering @Salauyou. I'm using principally ListView (both horizontal and vertical), ImageView and a VideoView. In addition, I'm using PullToRefreshListView with a little of customization from this repo [ https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore ]. In that classes there aren't usage of BitmapShader too. (at least, not explicit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a [ProgressBar](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java)? I noticed a ton of BitmapShaders in MAT for my application as well, and most of them are retained by a ProgressBar instance. I used the dominator tree view, then right-clicked on a BitmapShader instance, choosing 'Merge Shortest Paths to GC Roots' then 'exclude weak references'. Somewhere along the hierarchy that shows up is a ProgressBar.

Comment: OMG! I'm using LOTS of ProgressBars, with custom drawable animations.. How is possible that the progresses are the thing that use most of my app memory?! So, what shall we use to tell the user to wait? ImageViews?! It's crazy... I'll check with MAT, but I suppose that you've really hit the point...

Comment: So, you were right. the BitmapShader are retained by the ProgressBar instances.. But we can't eliminate progresses! Any idea?

Comment: I'm not using a crazy amount of ProgressBars. So fixing other memory leaks was sufficient for me. I don't think using a lot of ProgressBars in your app is a problem, unless you're retaining more than you need. You shouldn't need more than one or two on a given screen.

Comment: @Allison, could you clarify how you went about properly garbage collecting ProgressBar instances please?